# PHP code block doesn't send mails

Tags: php, html

I looked up some other questions about this problem, and none of them have codes similar to mine.
This is the code I used

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"]) && !empty($_POST["telefon"]){
    $msg = "Nume: " .$_POST["nume"] ." ". $_POST["prenume"] ."\n"
        ."Email: " .$_POST["email"] ."\n"
        ."Telefon: " .$_POST["telefon"] ."\n"
        ."Adresa: " .$_POST["adresa"];
        mail("not-gonna-show-my-mail-adress-but-its-valid", "Comanda de Magneti", $msg);
        header("location: multumim.php");
} else if (isset($_POST["submit"]) && empty($_POST["telefon"])){
    $msg = "Nume: " .$_POST["nume"] ." ". $_POST["prenume"] ."\n"
        ."Email: " .$_POST["email"] ."\n"
        ."Adresa: " .$_POST["adresa"];
        mail("not-gonna-show-my-mail-adress-but-its-valid", "Comanda de Magneti", $msg);
        header("location: multumim.php");
}else{
    header("location: comanda-magneti.html");
    exit(0);
}
?>
```

HTML

```
        <form style="font-size: 1.25em; margin-left: 20px;" method="post" target="comenzi.php">
            <label for="nume">Nume<span style="color: red;">*</span></label> <input id="nume" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Nume" title="nume">
            <label for="prenume">Prenume<span style="color: red;">*</span></label> <input id="prenume" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Prenume" title="prenume">
            <label for="email">E-Mail</label><span style="color: red;">*</span><input id="email" class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="E-Mail" title="email">
            <label for="telefon">Numar Telefon</label><input id="telefon" class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Numar Telefon" title="telefon">
            <label for="adresa">Adresa</label><span style="color: red;">*</span><input id="adresa" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Strada/Numar/Localitate/Judet" title="adresa"> <br />
            <input class="btn-default" type="submit" value="Comanda!"></input>
        </form>
```

Basically, I have 5 input fields, one for first name, one for last name, one for email, one for phone number (which is optional), and one for the adress.
In the PHP code I made an if statement that works if ALL the input fields are completed, and another if statement that works if the phone number wasn't entered.

After the form is completed, it's supposed to send the user to a "Thank You" page, and then just send the mail to me. When I do hit "submit", nothing happens. The page remains in the same place, and the form information goes nowhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of your inputs have `name` attributes so for example `$_POST["telefon"]` will always be empty.

You need:

```
<input name="telefon" id="telefon" class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Numar Telefon" title="telefon">
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this
// etc.
```

You should add error handling and check for return values of for example the `mail()` function to see what is happening at every stage.

Comment: That's it :D You always have to do your Input fields like: `<Input Name=" " id=" " class=" " type=" " placeholder=" ">`

Answer (score 0):

Insert name in input=submit

```
<input class="btn-default" type="submit" value="Comanda!" name="submit"></input>
```

Comment: This still doesn't work, do I need some kind of require or include function?

Comment: <form style="font-size: 1.25em; margin-left: 20px;" method="post" target="comenzi.php"> Alter target for action="comenzi.php"

Answer (score 0):

Your form-tag is missing the `action`-attribute (which is the target of the form submit). The `target`-attribute is the browser-window to open the target-url in.

Answer (score 0):

the mail php code only works when you are in an online web server if you are in a local server that won't work for you.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you earn sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post. If you have a related but different question, ask a new question referencing this one if it will help provide context.